# IBM MQ8.0.0.7 Queue Manager Startup issue

Tags: oracle, ibm-mq

Hi We are in the process of Migrationg MQ8.0.0.7 with Linux OS. We have created QueueManager. Also Created switch load file with oraClient 11.2.0.4.Updated switch file config in qm.ini file.

Switch file created usiing -- IBM MQ8.0.0.7 and oraClient 11.2.0.4

But When we try to start up the queue manager we are getting below error

```
04/10/2018 08:15:07 AM - Process(32092.1) User(mqm) Program(amqzxma0) Host(lswttsccsap5u) Installation(Installation1) VRMF(8.0.0.7) QMgr(NYCOLI2_QM.UATIN)

AMQ6175: The system could not dynamically load the shared library '/var/mqm/exits64/oraswit'. The system returned error message '/var/mqm/exits64/oraswit: undefined symbol: xaosw'.

EXPLANATION: This message applies to UNIX systems. The shared library '/var/mqm/exits64/oraswit' failed to load correctly due to a problem with the library. ACTION: Check the file access permissions and that the file has not been corrupted.
----- amqxufnx.c : 1436 ------------------------------------------------------- 
04/10/2018 08:15:07 AM - Process(32092.1) User(mqm) Program(amqzxma0) Host(lswttsccsap5u) Installation(Installation1) VRMF(8.0.0.7) QMgr(NYCOLI2_QM.UATIN)

AMQ7622: WebSphere MQ could not load the XA switch load file for resource manager 'Oracle_CMXIUAT_AIX'.
```

qm.ini file Stanza

```
XAResourceManager:
    Name=MyQueuManager
    SwitchFile=oraswit
    ThreadOfControl=THREAD 
    XAOpenString=Oracle_XA+Acc=P/myusername/mypassword+SesTm=100+dbgfl=15+LogDir=/var/mqm/xa_logs+dbgfl=15+SqlNet=SSS+threads=TRUE
```

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

The SwitchFile doesn't seem correct. Where did you get that from?

I found these for Linux:

```
Linux (nonthreaded)     libmqmxa64.so   libmqcxa64.so
Linux (threaded)    libmqmxa64_r.so     libmqcxa64_r.so
```

Check out the documentation for setting up XA:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sce.doc/q023610_.htm